# Repository inserts don't work in SpringBootTest with WebTestClient

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spock, webtestclient

I am converting a spring boot application to use webflux by making the endpoints reactive one at a time. Most of the (Spock) tests worked fine, but the ones where I autowire the JPA repository in the test to insert data do not. The repository is always empty when the resource (that we're testing) reads from it. I have tens of tests like this with different repositories and they all have same issue.

Here is an example of a test (the resource we're testing just does findById and returns the example from the repository):

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient(timeout = "60000")
@Transactional
class PaymentControllerIntegrationTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient client

    @Autowired
    PaymentRepository repo

    def "GET /example/{id} returns correct example"() {
        given:
        def needle = new Example(id: 1L)
        def haystack = repo.saveAll([needle, new Example(id: 2L), new Example(id: 3L)])

        when:
        def response = client.get().uri(EXAMPLE_URL, [id: needle.id.toString()]).exchange()

        then:
        response.expectStatus().isOk()
        response.returnResult(ExampleResponse.class).getResponseBody().blockLast().id == needle.id
    }
```

When I put a breakpoint in the controller and do findAll() the repository is always empty.

- I have tried using TestEntityManager.persistAndFlush instead
- I have tried using repo.saveAllAndFlush instead
- I have tried autowiring ApplicationContext and then building WebTestClient from that, but I never got the autowiring to work

My best guess currently is that the test is setup incorrectly (application context?) so the repository in the test is not the same as the repository in the application.

Comment: You are haveing 2 transactions, 1 not committed (the one from the test) and the 1 from the controller can thus not see the data (as it isn't committed yet). So it is the same repository but a different transaction.

Comment: @M.Deinum But why and how did that change when I started using WebTestClient instead of MockMvc?

Comment: Because now you are doing a real request, instead of using the mocked MVC. The mocking runs in the same transaction, as this is a real request to your controller it runs in a separate thread and thus transaction. The same would hebben with `TestRestTemplate` instead of `MockMvc`.

Comment: @M.Deinum if you add your comments as answer then OP can accept it.

Comment: Yes, please do. It definitely solved the issue (to remove @Transactional and delete data between tests).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `TestWebClient` (or the `TestRestTemplate`) you are actually issuing a real HTTP request to your started server. This request is handled in a different thread and as such uses a new transaction.

Your test is transactional as well but the data hasn't been committed, another transaction can only read committed data (or you need to set the isolation level to `READ_UNCOMMITTED` but that is probably not something you should or want to do).

When using `MockMvc` you are replacing the actual container with a mocked instance and it uses a `MockHttpServletRequest` etc. **and** executes in the same thread (and thus reuse the same transaction and can see the data).

To solve, make your test not transactional and cleanup the data afterwards. This will however impact the performance of your tests (as committing and then deleting is slower as rolling back a transaction after the test).