# No data received from WebTestClient when getting data from JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-test

I have a simple integration test case where I'd like to find a certain data.
First, I use .save() to insert a data. While it works successfully (as I debugged it and also this.dataRepository.findAll() does not return null), but when I use WebTestClient to get the specific data using the same method (this.dataRepository.findAll()), it returns null

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/constant")
public class ConfigurationController {

  @Autowired
  private DataRepository dataRepository;

  @GetMapping
  public Mono<Object> getConstant() {
    Mono.fromSupplier(() -> this.dataRepository.findAll()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.single());
  }
}
```

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
@Transactional
public class TestITCase {

  @Autowired
  private DataRepository dataRepository;

  @Autowired
  private WebTestClient webTestClient;

  @Test
  public void getConstants_Valid_Success()  {
    this.dataRepository.saveAndFlush(data);
    this.dataRepository.findAll(); // the data exist
    FluxExchangeResult<String> result = this.webTestClient.get()
        .uri(b -> b.path("/api/constant")
            .build())
        .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .exchange()
        .returnResult(String.class)
        .getResponseBody()
        .blockFirst(); // this returns null for some reason
  }
}
```

### UPDATE

Apparently when using WebTestClient,

> This request is handled in a different thread and as such uses a new transaction.
> [Repository inserts don't work in SpringBootTest with WebTestClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69389071/repository-inserts-dont-work-in-springboottest-with-webtestclient)

But now I'm wondering is there a way such that the WebTestClient is running on the same thread? Because I do not want to commit a transaction then roll it back, as it does not create idempotency within my test (for example the test failed before .delete()), then the data is accidentally saved.

Comment: The data isn't saved, it is only visible for the current thread / transaction. As the webclient is async it cannot see the non-committed data as it runs a different transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you mix WebFlux and JPA in the same project, if you mix Webmvc and WebFlux in the same Spring Boot project, the Webflux should not be enabled by default, when starting the application, it will bootstrap the application via Mvc stack.

We should avoid the traditional blocking Mvc stack and reactive WebFlux. But mixing JPA into a WebFlux application is possible. I have an WebFlux example project where use JPA and R2dbc.

https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/tree/master/jpa-r2dbc/

And tests using `WebTestClient` is also possible, https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/blob/master/jpa-r2dbc/src/test/java/com/example/demo/ApplicationTests.java